# Cannot pass an array of object to a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

I am trying to pass the selected values from a dropdown menu to a `handleSearch()` then this pass to a `filterList()`.

However, it does not reach to `filterList()`.

```
private handleSearch(e) {
    let key = e.key;
    let val = e.target.value;
    let type = e.target.type;
    let tname = e.target.name;
///code above
 if (type == "select-one") {
      let opt = [{ name: tname, value: val }]; //e.g. [{name:"Category",value:"abc"}]
      debugger;
      let page;
      this.filterList(
        this.state.searchvalue,
        page,
        this.state.selectVal ? this.state.selectVal : opt
      );
///code below
/// I can read the data here
```

```
 private filterList(query: string, ItemsPerPage = 10, options?) {
    let category = "";
    let users = "";
    let orderby = "Title";
    let order = "asc";
    if (options) { // undefined
      for (let i = 0; i <= options.length; i++) {
        if (options.name == "Category") {
/// codes continue
```

```html
<select name="Category" onChange={props.select}>
  <option value="">All Category</option>
  {cat.map(i => (
    <option value={i}>{i}</option>
  ))}
</select>;
```

props.select is defined as 
select={this.handleSearch} in the Parent Component
Did I miss something?

Comment: what is props.select?

Comment: this.handleSearch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know why > < i am looping a for loop.
thus

```
 if (options.name == "Category") {
```

should be

```
 if (options[i].name == "Category") {
```